# How can I remove the hard coding of the web service address from .ClientConfig files

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 5 SilverLight projects in my ASP .NET MVC 4 application. For each of these projects, there is a web service which passes data to and from the silverlight control.

When we deploy the application on the client's server, we update the `.ClientConfig` file of each SilverLight project by changing the address of the web service.

That is we change -

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:52213/SchemeReimbursementMasterService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SchemeReimbursementMasterServiceSoap"
            contract="SchemeServiceReference.SchemeReimbursementMasterServiceSoap"
            name="SchemeReimbursementMasterServiceSoap" />
```

to -

```
<endpoint address="http://192.168.5.48/SCHEME/SchemeReimbursementMasterService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SchemeReimbursementMasterServiceSoap"
            contract="SchemeServiceReference.SchemeReimbursementMasterServiceSoap"
            name="SchemeReimbursementMasterServiceSoap" />
```

Then we build it and publish the application.

So, in future, if the address changes, we would have to change it in all the five `.ClientConfig` files and build/publish it again. Is there any way we can remove this hardcoding so that it figures out the base part of the url (i.e: `http://192.168.5.48/SCHEME`/) on its own.

Answer (score 0):

In my application's `web.config`, I added keys for the service names.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ReviewUrl" value="ReviewClaimsService.asmx"/>
    <add key="ReimbursementUrl" value="SchemeReimbursementMasterService.asmx"/>
    <add key="DiscountUrl" value="DiscountMasterSchemeService.asmx"/>
</appSettings>
```

In the controller, I created the URL using the `HttpContext` and the service name from `web.config`  and passed it to the view.

```
var baseUrl = "http://" + HttpContext.Request.Headers["Host"];
var applicationPath = HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath;
if (applicationPath == "/")
    baseUrl = baseUrl + "/";
var url = baseUrl + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReimbursementUrl"];
```

In the View, I passed this URL to the `silverlight` control using `InitParams`.

```
<object id="TownsGrid" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2">
    <param name="InitParams" value="ControlName=TownDataGrid,ServiceUrl=@Model.ServiceUrl" />
    <param name="source" value="@Url.Content("~/ClientBin/SilverlightApplication.xap")"/>
</object>
```

In the `Application_Startup` method of the silverlight project, I passed the URL on to the SilverLight control.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var url = e.InitParams["ServiceUrl"];
    this.RootVisual = new SilverlightApplication.TownDataGrid(url);
}
```

And finally, in the silverlight control, I assign the url to the endpoint.

```
public TownDataGrid(string serviceUrl)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    client = new SchemeReimbursementMasterServiceSoapClient(binding,endpoint);
}
```

Comment: You will end up in changing app config for each client.